# Modal and collaspe doesn't work on bootstrap after copy/paste

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a little problem with bootstrap, indeed, after copying/pasting a page that contained a modal and a collapse, on the copy they no longer work. While on the original they work perfectly. Do you know what this could come from please?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions, it is ideal that you share your code, this way it is easier to help and identify exactly where the error is. I will still try to help you.

Make sure you enter the Bootstrap related links:

CSS:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

JS:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you have already done this, check if the name of the modal IDs is the same as the one in the `data-target` of the button that triggers it.

Same ID logic for collapse as well.

Sources: [Bootstrap Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/), [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), [Bootstrap Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Comment: I have already done what you are telling me, but unfortunately nothing work :/ . I also checked that all the tags were closed and they are all closed